# How to properly fetch data on user click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to display a menu with three tags `Streaming`,`On Tv` and `In Theaters` similar to what you can find on https://www.themoviedb.org/

The default data that is displayed is the `Streaming` section, which is receiving JSON from `getStaticProps`. I only want to fetch `On Tv` and `In Theaters` endpoints if the user clicks on it, and later cache that information. This is my code so far (only `On Tv` example, though `In theaters` would be the same):

```
import useSWR from 'swr'
import React, { useState } from "react";

const fetcher = async (e) => {
    const res = await fetch(e);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data
};
  
const Trending = ({data}) => {
    const [media, setMedia] = useState(data); //data used to display shows/movies
    const [onTv, setOnTv] = useState(null);
    
    const [shouldFetchTv, setShouldFetchTv] = useState(false);
    const urls = [
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/on_the_air?api_key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1&region=US`
    ]

    const tv = useSWR(shouldFetchTv && urls[0], fetcher);
    const tvResult = tv.data;
    
    const handleTv = () =>  {
        onTv ? setMedia(onTv) //if onTv has data then just set it
        :
        setShouldFetchTv(true); //fetches endpoint on users click
        setOnTv(tvResult); // caches the data
        setMedia(onTv); //sets media object with the cached data
    }

   (...Some more code)
       <div onClick={handleTv}>  
          <h1>On Tv</h1>
          </div>
```

The problem is that `onTv` object doesn't get properly defined on the first click, but on the third. I've been trying to implement useEffect to no effect (no pun intended), but I'm still learning hooks so maybe I'm missing something. How can I get it to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

On first click `shouldFetchTv` is false and `onTv` is null. `shouldFetchTv` sets to true

On second click `shouldFetchTv && urls[0]` becomes true and async request is sent, `tvResult = tv.data` is null because it async

On third click you send second request and result of first is available so it sets `onTv`

On fourth click `onTv` is not null

Because `useSWR` is using browser cache async result is available on third click

Comment: Thanks for answering! I get what's going on, but I can't manage to make all those steps happen simultaneously...

Comment: @LeoM useSWR is already does all caching and request deduplication, so you don't need shouldFetchTv and setOnTv/setMedia. Read the docs https://swr.vercel.app/